# Google+ Api Deprecated

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-people-api

I was Using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" api, in which I was able to access to a list of people in the user's circles in addition to their name and profile information. After api deprecation, I started using people.connections.list api "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections" as per documentation, but I am getting list of contacts only, not friends list in Google+ circle.Can anyone help me out to retrieve the friends list in Google+.

Comment: You can't retrieve a list of friends or connections on the Google plus social media site this information has not been exposed

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. Is there is any other alternative solution for this..?

Comment: Nope not a one unless you want to play with site scraping. Google doesn't want to make this information public via an API so you have no way of getting it.